# Theano error: ValueError: y_i value out of bounds.

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, theano, lasagne

I'm trying to get my own data to work with a convolutional neural network in theano/lasagne.

A state consists of 4 80x80 images. There are 32 states in a batch and the batch is the input to the neural network. The output of the network has 5 units. (Relating to the 5 possible actions in the game) **also see edit 2**

Before training the model, the program observes states. When testing the training function I set the observations to only 500 and everything was fine. But when I set the observations to 50 000, I suddenly get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "snake_player.py", line 320, in <module>
  import snake
File "C:\A Bright Future\machine-learning\snake\PyGamePlayer-master\examples\snake.py", line 124, in <module>
  pygame.display.update()
File "C:\A Bright Future\machine-learning\snake\PyGamePlayer-master\examples\pygame_player.py", line 28, in wrap
  intercepted_results = intercepting_func(real_results, *args, **kwargs)  # call our own function a
File "C:\A Bright Future\machine-learning\snake\PyGamePlayer-master\examples\pygame_player.py", line 149, in _on_screen_update
  keys = self.get_keys_pressed(surface_array, reward, terminal)
File "snake_player.py", line 126, in get_keys_pressed
  self._train()
File "snake_player.py", line 237, in _train
  self._train_err += train_fn(previous_states, agents_expected_reward)
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 871, in __call__
  storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\link.py", line 314, in raise_with_op
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 859, in __call__
  outputs = self.fn()
ValueError: y_i value out of bounds
Apply node that caused the error: CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias(Dot22.0, b, targets)
Toposort index: 50
Inputs types: [TensorType(float64, matrix), TensorType(float64, vector), TensorType(int32, vector)]
Inputs shapes: [(32L, 5L), (5L,), (32L,)]
Inputs strides: [(40L, 8L), (8L,), (4L,)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', array([ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1]), 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[Sum{acc_dtype=float64}(CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias.0)], [CrossentropySoftmax1HotWithBiasDx(TensorConstant{(32L,) of 0.03125}, CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias.1, targets)], []]
```

Debugprint of the apply node:

```
CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias.0 [id A] <TensorType(float64, vector)> ''
 |Dot22 [id B] <TensorType(float64, matrix)> ''
 | |Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (Abs(i1) + i2 + i3))}}[(0, 2)] [id C] <TensorType(float64, matrix)> ''
 | | |TensorConstant{(1L, 1L) of 0.5} [id D] <TensorType(float64, (True, True))>
 | | |Elemwise{add,no_inplace} [id E] <TensorType(float64, matrix)> ''
 | | | |Dot22 [id F] <TensorType(float64, matrix)> ''
 | | | | |Reshape{2} [id G] <TensorType(float64, matrix)> ''
 | | | | | |Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (Abs(i1) + i2 + i3))}}[(0, 2)] [id H] <TensorType(float64, 4D)> ''
 | | | | | | |TensorConstant{(1L, 1L, 1..1L) of 0.5} [id I] <TensorType(float64, (True, True, True, True))>
 | | | | | | |Elemwise{add,no_inplace} [id J] <TensorType(float64, 4D)> ''
 | | | | | | | |ConvOp{('imshp', (64, 8, 8)),('kshp', (3, 3)),('nkern', 64),('bsize', None),('dx', 1),('dy', 1),('out_mode', 'valid'),('unroll_batch', None),('unroll_kern', None),('unroll_patch', True),('imshp_logical', (64, 8, 8)),('kshp_logical', (3, 3)),('kshp_logical_top_aligned', True)} [id K] <TensorType(float64, 4D)> ''
 | | | | | | | | |Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (Abs(i1) + i2 + i3))}}[(0, 2)] [id L] <TensorType(float64, 4D)> ''
 | | | | | | | | | |TensorConstant{(1L, 1L, 1..1L) of 0.5} [id I] <TensorType(float64, (True, True, True, True))>
 | | | | | | | | | |Elemwise{add,no_inplace} [id M] <TensorType(float64, 4D)> ''
 | | | | | | | | | | |ConvOp{('imshp', (32, 19, 19)),('kshp', (4, 4)),('nkern', 64),('bsize', None),('dx', 2),('dy', 2),('out_mode', 'valid'),('unroll_batch', None),('unroll_kern', None),('unroll_patch', True),('imshp_logical', (32, 19, 19)),('kshp_logical', (4, 4)),('kshp_logical_top_aligned', True)} [id N] <TensorType(float64, 4D)> ''
 | | | | | | | | | | | |Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (Abs(i1) + i2 + i3))}}[(0, 2)] [id O] <TensorType(float64, 4D)> ''
 | | | | | | | | | | | | |TensorConstant{(1L, 1L, 1..1L) of 0.5} [id I] <TensorType(float64, (True, True, True, True))>
 | | | | | | | | | | | | |Elemwise{add,no_inplace} [id P] <TensorType(float64, 4D)> ''
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | |ConvOp{('imshp', (4, 80, 80)),('kshp', (8, 8)),('nkern', 32),('bsize', None),('dx', 4),('dy', 4),('out_mode', 'valid'),('unroll_batch', None),('unroll_kern', None),('unroll_patch', True),('imshp_logical', (4, 80, 80)),('kshp_logical', (8, 8)),('kshp_logical_top_aligned', True)} [id Q] <TensorType(float64, 4D)> '
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |TensorConstant{[[[[ 1.   ..      ]]]]} [id R] <TensorType(float64, 4D)>
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |W [id S] <TensorType(float64, 4D)>
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | |InplaceDimShuffle{x,0,x,x} [id T] <TensorType(float64, (True, False, True, True))> ''
 | | | | | | | | | | | | |   |b [id U] <TensorType(float64, vector)>
 | | | | | | | | | | | | |ConvOp{('imshp', (4, 80, 80)),('kshp', (8, 8)),('nkern', 32),('bsize', None),('dx', 4),('dy', 4),('out_mode', 'valid'),('unroll_batch', None),('unroll_kern', None),('unroll_patch', True),('imshp_logical', (4, 80, 80)),('kshp_logical', (8, 8)),('kshp_logical_top_aligned', True)} [id Q] <TensorType(float64, 4D)> ''
 | | | | | | | | | | | | |InplaceDimShuffle{x,0,x,x} [id T] <TensorType(float64, (True, False, True, True))> ''
 | | | | | | | | | | | |W [id V] <TensorType(float64, 4D)>
 | | | | | | | | | | |InplaceDimShuffle{x,0,x,x} [id W] <TensorType(float64, (True, False, True, True))> ''
 | | | | | | | | | |   |b [id X] <TensorType(float64, vector)>
 | | | | | | | | | |ConvOp{('imshp', (32, 19, 19)),('kshp', (4, 4)),('nkern', 64),('bsize', None),('dx', 2),('dy', 2),('out_mode', 'valid'),('unroll_batch', None),('unroll_kern', None),('unroll_patch', True),('imshp_logical', (32, 19, 19)),('kshp_logical', (4, 4)),('kshp_logical_top_aligned', True)} [id N] <TensorType(float64, 4D)> ''
 | | | | | | | | | |InplaceDimShuffle{x,0,x,x} [id W] <TensorType(float64, (True, False, True, True))> ''
 | | | | | | | | |W [id Y] <TensorType(float64, 4D)>
 | | | | | | | |InplaceDimShuffle{x,0,x,x} [id Z] <TensorType(float64, (True, False, True, True))> ''
 | | | | | | |   |b [id BA] <TensorType(float64, vector)>
 | | | | | | |ConvOp{('imshp', (64, 8, 8)),('kshp', (3, 3)),('nkern', 64),('bsize', None),('dx', 1),('dy', 1),('out_mode', 'valid'),('unroll_batch', None),('unroll_kern', None),('unroll_patch', True),('imshp_logical', (64, 8, 8)),('kshp_logical', (3, 3)),('kshp_logical_top_aligned', True)} [id K] <TensorType(float64, 4D)> ''
 | | | | | | |InplaceDimShuffle{x,0,x,x} [id Z] <TensorType(float64, (True, False, True, True))> ''
 | | | | | |TensorConstant{[32 -1]} [id BB] <TensorType(int64, vector)>
 | | | | |W [id BC] <TensorType(float64, matrix)>
 | | | |InplaceDimShuffle{x,0} [id BD] <TensorType(float64, row)> ''
 | | |   |b [id BE] <TensorType(float64, vector)>
 | | |Dot22 [id F] <TensorType(float64, matrix)> ''
 | | |InplaceDimShuffle{x,0} [id BD] <TensorType(float64, row)> ''
 | |W [id BF] <TensorType(float64, matrix)>
 |b [id BG] <TensorType(float64, vector)>
 |targets [id BH] <TensorType(int32, vector)>
CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias.1 [id A] <TensorType(float64, matrix)> ''
CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias.2 [id A] <TensorType(int32, vector)> ''
```

The storage map footprint:

```
Storage map footprint:
- W, Shared Input, Shape: (2304L, 512L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 9437184 Byte(s)
- TensorConstant{[[[[ 1.   ..      ]]]]}, Shape: (32L, 4L, 80L, 80L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 6553600 Byte(s)
- <TensorType(float64, 4D)>, Shared Input, Shape: (32L, 4L, 80L, 80L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 6553600 Byte(s)
- inputs, Input, Shape: (32L, 80L, 80L, 4L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 6553600 Byte(s)
- Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0, Shape: (32L, 32L, 19L, 19L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 2957312 Byte(s)
- Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (Abs(i1) + i2 + i3))}}[(0, 2)].0, Shape: (32L, 32L, 19L, 19L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 2957312 Byte(s)
 - Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0, Shape: (32L, 64L, 8L, 8L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 1048576 Byte(s)
 - Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (Abs(i1) + i2 + i3))}}[(0, 2)].0, Shape: (32L, 64L, 8L, 8L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 1048576 Byte(s)
 - Reshape{2}.0, Shape: (32L, 2304L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 589824 Byte(s)
 - Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0, Shape: (32L, 64L, 6L, 6L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 589824 Byte(s)
 - W, Shared Input, Shape: (64L, 64L, 3L, 3L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 294912 Byte(s)
 - W, Shared Input, Shape: (64L, 32L, 4L, 4L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 262144 Byte(s)
 - Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0, Shape: (32L, 512L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 131072 Byte(s)
 - Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (Abs(i1) + i2 + i3))}}[(0, 2)].0, Shape: (32L, 512L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 131072 Byte(s)
 - W, Shared Input, Shape: (32L, 4L, 8L, 8L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 65536 Byte(s)
 - W, Shared Input, Shape: (512L, 5L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 20480 Byte(s)
 - b, Shared Input, Shape: (512L,), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 4096 Byte(s)
 - Dot22.0, Shape: (32L, 5L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 1280 Byte(s)
- b, Shared Input, Shape: (64L,), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 512 Byte(s)
 - b, Shared Input, Shape: (64L,), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 512 Byte(s)
 - b, Shared Input, Shape: (32L,), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 256 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{(32L,) of 0.03125}, Shape: (32L,), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 256 Byte(s)
 - targets, Input, Shape: (32L,), ElemSize: 4 Byte(s), TotalSize: 128 Byte(s)
 - b, Shared Input, Shape: (5L,), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 40 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{[32 64  6  6]}, Shape: (4L,), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 32 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{(2L,) of 19}, Shape: (2L,), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 16 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{[32 -1]}, Shape: (2L,), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 16 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{[4 4 1]}, Shape: (3L,), ElemSize: 4 Byte(s), TotalSize: 12 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{[2 2 1]}, Shape: (3L,), ElemSize: 4 Byte(s), TotalSize: 12 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{(1L,) of 1e-06}, Shape: (1L,), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{0.0}, Shape: (), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8.0 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{0.03125}, Shape: (), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8.0 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{(1L, 1L) of 0.5}, Shape: (1L, 1L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{(1L, 1L, 1..1L) of 0.5}, Shape: (1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{(1L, 1L, 1..) of 1e-06}, Shape: (1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8 Byte(s)
 - Constant{-1}, Shape: (), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8.0 Byte(s)
 - Constant{4}, Shape: (), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8.0 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{0.5}, Shape: (), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8.0 Byte(s)
 - Constant{1}, Shape: (), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8.0 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{-1e-06}, Shape: (), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8.0 Byte(s)
 - Constant{0}, Shape: (), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8.0 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{1.0}, Shape: (), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8.0 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{1}, Shape: (), ElemSize: 1 Byte(s), TotalSize: 1.0 Byte(s)
 TotalSize: 39201897.0 Byte(s) 0.037 GB
 TotalSize inputs: 29747049.0 Byte(s) 0.028 GB
```

My training function looks like this:

```
def _train(self):
    start_time = time.time()
    # Prepare Theano variables for inputs and targets
    input_variable = T.tensor4('inputs')
    states = T.tensor4('states')
    expected = T.tensor4('expected')
    real_rewards = T.tensor4('rewards')
    print "sampling mini batch..."
    # sample a mini_batch to train on
    mini_batch = random.sample(self._observations, self.MINI_BATCH_SIZE)
    # get the batch variables
    previous_states = [d[self.OBS_LAST_STATE_INDEX] for d in mini_batch]
    actions = [d[self.OBS_ACTION_INDEX] for d in mini_batch]
    rewards = [d[self.OBS_REWARD_INDEX] for d in mini_batch]
    current_states = np.array([d[self.OBS_CURRENT_STATE_INDEX] for d in mini_batch])
    agents_expected_reward = []
    print "compiling current states..."
    current_states = np.rollaxis(current_states, 3, 1)

    print "getting network output from current states..."
    agents_reward_per_action = lasagne.layers.get_output(self._output_layer, current_states)

    self._train_err = 0
    print "rewards adding..."
    for i in range(len(mini_batch)):
        if mini_batch[i][self.OBS_TERMINAL_INDEX]:
            agents_expected_reward.append(rewards[i])
        else:
            agents_expected_reward.append(
                rewards[i] + self.FUTURE_REWARD_DISCOUNT * np.max(agents_reward_per_action[i].eval()))

    network = self._output_layer
    prediction = agents_reward_per_action
    loss = lasagne.objectives.categorical_crossentropy(prediction, target_var)
    loss = loss.mean()

    params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(network, trainable=True)
    updates = lasagne.updates.sgd(loss, params, self.LEARN_RATE)
    givens = {
        states: current_states,
        expected: agents_expected_reward,
        real_rewards: rewards
    }
    train_fn = theano.function([input_var, target_var], loss,
                                    updates=updates, on_unused_input='warn',
                                    givens=givens,
                                    allow_input_downcast='True')

    self._train_err += train_fn(previous_states, agents_expected_reward)
```

I don't understand why it happens at 50 000 observations but not at 500.
The only thing that changes is the amount of observations, why is it suddenly 'out of bounds'. Any ideas on why this is happening? Every answer is hugely appreciated. Thank you.

The full code is here:

- main file: http://pastebin.com/y53VAauT
- Snake game file: http://pastebin.com/Xx4aPRu7
- pygame player file: http://pastebin.com/EKAYt5N8 (to get the game score and send actions)

Edit: It also happens at 1000 and up. Still have no clue why.

**Edit 2:** I've found that the problem relates to the reward. Because the model is not trained yet, it mostly makes random moves. So that's why the problem occurs at the higher number of observations. (Higher chance of the reward being higher than 5) And it gives an error when the reward (the length of the snake) is higher then 5 which is odd because 5 is the number of possible actions (output of the neural network). Getting closer to the solution!